# Independent and identical

Tags: summation, normal-distribution, independence

I have $X_1,X_2, \cdots X_n$ that are iid from $N(\mu,\sigma)$. In my derivation of the expression

$E \big( \sum^n_{i=1} X_i^2 \big)$

I have written

$E \big( \sum^n_{i=1} X_i^2 \big) = \sum^n_{i=1} E \big( X_i^2 \big) = n E \big( X_i^2 \big) $

Is it true that first $=$ is because $X_1,X_2, \cdots X_n$ are independent and the second $=$ is because they are identical?

Comment: First equality is by linearity of the expectation operator.

Comment: For the first, you don't need  independence. They are identical, yes; that is important.

Comment: "are identical" should read "have the same distribution".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expected value operator, $\mathbb{E}[.]$, is linear in the sense that

- $\mathbb{E}[X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n]=\mathbb{E}[X_1]+\mathbb{E}[X_2]+\cdots+\mathbb{E}[X_n]$
- $\mathbb{E}[\lambda X]=\lambda\mathbb{E}[X] ,\quad \lambda\in \mathbb{R}.$

We have 
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[X_i^2]$$
$X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$have same distribution, thus
$$\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[X^2_i]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\sigma^2+\mu^2)=n(\sigma^2+\mu^2)$$

Comment: I don't understand why $\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i^2\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[X_i]$

Comment: @JeanMarie Me too.

Comment: @Felix Marin -:) It was typo

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki I imagined it was a typo. Pedagogical answer.

Comment: So thanks .. :D

Comment: "are identical" should read "have the same distribution".

Comment: Yes, I will edit it.